# Why don't The Daedric princes just take over Tamriel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls

Throughout all the elder scrolls games I've played, The daedric princes seem to have A LOT of power - In oblivion, sheogorath could summon burning wolves from the sky, Clavicus vile could grant wishes in small ways, Hermaeus Mora appeared and killed someone personally in skyrim, the list goes on.

I understand that they have the dragonfires in oblivion to stop them, but from what I could gather its specifically to hold back Mehrunes Dagon. so why can't the other princes break through into tamriel and take over?

Comment: I think your question title went wrong somehow, it's a completely different question than the one you ask in the content of your question. I think you might be missing a "don't" in there?

Comment: Is there any indication that they *want* to take over Tamriel, aside from Mehrunes Dagon?

Comment: I *think* they can't come to Tamriel without help from this side but I'll have to dig through some lore to prove it. The dragonfires were meant to seal up a breach that Mehrunes Dagon's followers helped him make, IIRC.

Comment: also, FYI: no need to put the tag in the title. I cleaned that up for you a bit.

Answer (score 7):

There are, in fact, TWO things keeping the Daedric Princes in check - the Covenant of Akatosh as well as the Pact.

The Covenant of Akatosh was a deal made between Akatosh, leader of the Aedra, and Alessia, queen of the first Human Empire.

> "Akatosh drew from his breast a burning handful of his Heart's blood,
>   and he gave it into Alessia's hand, saying, 'This shall also be a
>   token to you of our joined blood and pledged faith. So long as you and
>   your descendants shall wear the Amulet of Kings, then shall this
>   dragonfire burn -- an eternal flame -- as a sign to all men and gods
>   of our faithfulness. So long as the dragonfires shall burn, to you,
>   and to all generations, I swear that my Heart's blood shall hold fast
>   the Gates of Oblivion."  ― Covenant in the [Trials of St. Alessia](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Trials_of_St._Alessia)

The Covenant between Akatosh and Alessia is powerful, but it only prevents a full-scale invasion of Tamriel - it literally prevents a Daedric Prince from opening gateways between their plane of Oblivion and Mundus.

There is a second covenant - known as the Pact - that was made between the Aedra & Daedra millennia ago. The Pact decrees that no Daedric Prince may fully interfere with Mundus, or enter another Prince's plane of Oblivion, unless invited. In his frustration & anger, Mehrunes Dagon broke this rule when he physically stepped into the realm of Mundus at the end of Oblivion. As a result, Akatosh himself took action and joined with Martin Septim to drive Dagon back to the Deadlands. Ideally, this second covenant is enforced by the Nine Divines and the Daedric Princes themselves, but realistically there is a good deal of flexibility in its enforcement.

Comment: Do you have any links that give more detail on the Pact? I can't find much about it at UESP.

Comment: @amaranth - I don't think there's much lore about it, just a couple of passing references in the in-game books. If I can find more, though, I'll add it to the answer.